# Model not getting assigned values on form submit

Tags: c#, html, .net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I'm new to MVC and have the following ActionMethod in my controller:

```
 public async Task<ActionResult> ViewSsoProviders(int? page, string nameFilter = "", string bpIdFilter = "",
        string protocolFilter = "")
```

I'm trying to call it through the following form in my view:

```
@{
using (Html.BeginForm("ViewSsoProviders", "SsoAdmin", new
{
    page = 1,
    nameFilter = Model.ProviderNameFilter,
    bpIdfilter = Model.BusinessPartnerIdFilter,
    protocolFilter = Model.ProtocolFilterSelection
}))
{
    <div id="providerForm">
        @Html.ValidationSummary()
        <div class="form-group row">
            <span class="col-sm-4">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ProviderNameFilter)
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ProviderNameFilter, new {@class = "form-control"})
            </span>
            <span class="col-sm-4">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.BusinessPartnerIdFilter)
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.BusinessPartnerIdFilter, new {@class = "form-control", style = "display: block"})
            </span>
            <span class="col-sm-4">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ProtocolFilterOptions)
                @Html.TranslatedDropDownListFor(m => m.ProtocolFilterSelection, Model.ProtocolFilterOptions, new {id = "ddlProtocols", @class = "form-control"})
            </span>
        </div>
        <button class="btn" type="submit" value="Filter">@Html.Translate("Filter")</button>
    </div>
```

The method is being hit, however, the filters have not been assigned values, I can hardcode the 'page' variable and it will reach my controller with the correct value, so the issue is not in the routing itself. Is there any obvious reason here why my route variables would be failing to be assigned values?

Edit: It's worth noting that if I instead pass 'null' rather than any routevalues in the view, I can pass a model through to the controller with only the fields on the form assigned data.

Comment: What result you are getting from RouteData.Values["page"]?

Comment: @Kadir I evaluated the RouteData in the controller when the form hits it and page does not appear in the list of values, nor do any of my other expected variables.

Comment: Why don't you just remove all the fitlers you have added in the method and simply pass it the view model?

Comment: @JamesS thanks for the suggestion, but I have paging on the results table which does not carry the filters over if you move to the next page, I know that the paging works if I can pass filters through this way. I may have to rethink the architecture but I've felt very close to the correct answer a few times. MVC is infinitely helpful but can be so frustrating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are submitting a form which should be a post. You should have a new method and decorate it with:

```
[HttpPost]
```

and parameterize it with another model or view model that holds the properties you need to get.

Ex.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ViewSsoProviders(MyViewModel model)
{
     //Do a redirection to ViewSoProviders
     //ex.
     return RedirectToAction("ViewSsoProviders", new {nameFilter = model.NameFiler, bpIdFilter = model.BpIdFilter, protocolFilter= model.ProtocolFilter });
}
```

And specify the form method on your razor view:

```
Html.BeginForm("ViewSsoProviders", "SsoAdmin", FormMethod.Post, new
{
    page = 1,
    nameFilter = Model.ProviderNameFilter,
    bpIdfilter = Model.BusinessPartnerIdFilter,
    protocolFilter = Model.ProtocolFilterSelection
}))
```

Comment: @Luke_Villanueva This is what I wanted, thanks a lot!